how to connect ADO.NET and SQL with C++
I'm developing in C++ to which I want to add a SQL database and connect it with ADO.NET. I need to add int, string, string, string, string double, int, int to the database. And upon request, this data must be received.
I've tried to find examples but I can't. Maybe someone can add a link with a code example of how to write with ADO.NET to a SQL database and how to read the information?

what's wrong with just coding it in C# ??? if you plan to run this on any platform other than windows you will have to write it in C#

@AhmedAEK All project is written on C++, I can not change it.

Are you ever planning on running it on any platform other than windows ? Your next choice will make it impossible to migrate so you need to specify that

@AhmedAEK only windows.

The best option in terms of ease of programming is to expose ADO.net through a COM Object written in C# then consume it in C++, Biggest problem is loading the Dotnet framework runtime in C++, which is easily done by COM under the hood, i think C++\CLI can replace C# buy i don't know if you can write COM components in C++\CLI

You will need to use the .NET implementation of C++, commonly known as C++/CLI. See  .NET programming with C++/CLI

Hello! Maybe you know how I can Add .NET to MFC project?

Sorry, I have never tried it, as it is so much easier to use C#.
